# Creating Navigation Tabs in Android

Tags: android, tabs, action

I'm new to Android (and Java to some extent).

My question is how can I create a tabbed action bar for navigation in an Android Application?

The possibilities and variances are mind boggling and i cant tell what is useful or not.

On the Android developer site it says you can use navigation tabs with fragments but all i want the navigation tabs to do is start activities so fragments seems overcomplicated and unnecessary.

All I want is a nice tabbed navigation bar with three options. I also have one option in the action bar for a quick action. Some sites are suggesting action bar sherlock but this is throwing up errors that i cant seem to fix.

Surely i dont have to download a whole separate library just to make a tabbed action bar that starts activities when each is touched.

(sorry im really new to this and Android is totally impenetrable at the moment)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the action bar api:

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html

Also, realize that you don't need to download "extra" libraries.

Comment: I have. As i said Android is quite impenetrable to me at the moment. I need more specifics than take a look at this because I dont understand what im reading. 

I want a tabbed navigation bar. I don't want to use fragments because i dont understand the need for them. I just want to create a navigation bar that starts activities.

Comment: If you only care about Android 3.0+, you don't need ActionBarSherlock.  A Fragment is just like an Activity, and is required to do any serious Android development, including the Tabbed interface of ActionBar.  Follow the sample apps available on the developer site and use those as a baseline for building your own app.

Comment: Okay. Im starting to understand fragments a little better. I'd be happy to close this question if someone could clear one last thing up for me.

Assuming I click tab a and open fragment A, can this fragment now set a ContentView from an XML file and do stuff with it like add listeners for buttons, populate a listView from a DB etc etc

Comment: Read the developer page on Fragments ... it works VERY similar to Activity, but has onCreateView() method where you can load your layout from xml just like an Activity

Answer (score 1):

I am an Android developer and when I first started, figuring out all of the ways to build Android apps was overwhelming. Navigational tabs were my worst issue. You can read all about tabs [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html#Tabs). If you would like some code examples there are repositories on Github like [this](https://github.com/AMQTech/Fixed-Tabs) one.

Hope this helps,

Andrew